# Aggregating a pandas data frame and deleting non required rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, max, aggregate, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame on which I want to perfom an aggregation and get rid of some rows that are not required basis a certain condition

```
ID  Type                     Band      Event            Date        Function       Title                Country 
1   Lead  Jr                   L       Hire             07/06/2016  PM          Lead Product Specialist India 
1   Lead  Jr                   L       Job Change       01/03/2019  PM          Lead Product Specialist India
1   Lead  Jr                   L       Job Change       01/03/2019  PM          Lead Product Specialist India
1   Lead  Sr                   S       Promotion        25/07/2019  PM          Lead Project Manager    India
2   Trainee                    P       Job Change       25/07/2016  AM          Trainee                 Australia
2   SW Developer               L       Promotion        25/07/2017  AM          Developer Lead          Australia
2   SW Developer               L       Job Change       25/07/2018  AM          Developer Lead          Australia
2   Lead  Specialist           S       Promotion        25/07/2019  AM          Lead Project Manager    Australia
3   Lead  Specialist           S       Promotion        25/10/2019  AM          Lead Project Manager    Australia
4   Sr  Specialist             S       Promotion        25/11/2019  AM          Lead Project Manager    Australia
```

and I want the following output from the data:

```
ID  Type                Band       Event            Date        Function       Title               Country 
1   Lead  Jr             L         Job Change    01/03/2019     PM       Lead Product Specialist     India
1   Lead  Sr             S         Promotion     25/07/2019     PM       Lead Project Manager        India
2   Trainee              P         Job Change    25/07/2016     AM       Trainee                   Australia
2   SW Developer         L         Job Change    25/07/2018     AM       Developer Lead            Australia
2   Lead  Specialist     L         Promotion     25/07/2019     AM       Lead Project Manager      Australia
3   Lead  Specialist     S         Promotion     25/10/2019     AM       Lead Project Manager      Australia
4   Sr  Specialist       S         Promotion     25/11/2019     AM       Lead Project Manager      Australia
```

**So essentially the logic is that I need to get the unique record basis the grouping at Type and band level and taking that record with the latest date, meaning the latest record. So if there are three records with Band = "L" and Type = "Lead Jr" with three different dates, then I need to take the latest record basis the date out of these three and so on.**

Comment: You can group by `Type` and `Band`, inversely sort by `Date` and take the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use [pandas.DataFrame.sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) & [pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

```py
# date to datetime
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

# depending on the data, optionally sort
df.sort_values(['ID', 'Type', 'Date'], inplace=True)

# drop_duplicates with keep='last'
df.drop_duplicates(['ID', 'Type', 'Band'], keep='last')  # optionally add .reset_index(drop=True)
```

## sort and drop_duplicates as a single line

```py
df.sort_values(['ID', 'Type', 'Date']).drop_duplicates(['ID', 'Type', 'Band'], keep='last')
```

### Result

```py
   ID              Type Band       Event       Date Function                    Title   Country 
2   1          Lead  Jr    L  Job Change 2019-01-03       PM  Lead Product Specialist      India
3   1          Lead  Sr    S   Promotion 2019-07-25       PM     Lead Project Manager      India
7   2  Lead  Specialist    S   Promotion 2019-07-25       AM     Lead Project Manager  Australia
6   2      SW Developer    L  Job Change 2018-07-25       AM           Developer Lead  Australia
4   2           Trainee    P  Job Change 2016-07-25       AM                  Trainee  Australia
8   3  Lead  Specialist    S   Promotion 2019-10-25       AM     Lead Project Manager  Australia
9   4    Sr  Specialist    S   Promotion 2019-11-25       AM     Lead Project Manager  Australia
```

Comment: Perfect! Solved my problem! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you sort the dataframe inversely by Date, then within each group, the data is sorted in that way as well, so you can safely take the first one.

```
df.sort_values("Date", ascending=False).groupby(["Type", "Band"]).first()
```